# Green function for high order Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

Let $-\Delta$ be the Laplacian operator. I have one question. What is the Green's solution to the following equation?

$${(-\Delta)}^n u(x,y) = \delta(x-y),\quad x,y \in \mathbb{R}^m,~ n \in \mathbb{N},~ n > m.  $$

Note that $y$ is a arbitrary variable.

Comment: What is Green's solution?

Comment: yes. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function